# How filter a table ( comparing a transformed data using a pipe ) in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, filter, html-table, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to filter a Table in Angular using a search box and a custom pipe.
Some values are showed in the table using pipes like:

```
 {{order.tot | currency: 'EUR':'symbol':'.2-2':'it' }}
 {{order.datePayment | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss' }}
```

Here the custom pipe:

```
export class SearchFilterOrdersPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(orders, searchValue: string): unknown {

    if (!orders || !searchValue) {
      return orders;
    }

    searchValue = searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return orders.filter(order =>
      order.idOrder.toString().includes(searchValue) ||
      order.email.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchValue) ||
      order.invoice.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchValue) ||
        //  order.datePayment.toString().includes(searchValue) ||
      order.paypalPaymentId.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchValue) ||
        //  order.tot.toString().includes(searchValue) ||
      order.status.includes(searchValue)
    )
  }
}
```

For all the string values of the table I don't have any problem. But 'tot' and 'datePayment' are originally in the format:

- order.datePayment: 2021-01-13T09:27:11.000Z
- order.tot: 100 or 15.50 or 20

So I will never catch the right values ( if for example i search the data '17/01/2021' or the tot like 15,50 ).

Is there some way to transform also in the pipe 'datePayment' and 'tot' before the .includes() ??

THX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe in your html is only used for displaying so you won't be able to access it in your pipe. It is possible to inject the pipes and transform them again:

```
export class SearchFilterOrdersPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private date: DatePipe, private curreny: CurrencyPipe) {
  }

  transform(orders, searchValue: string): unknown {
    if (!orders || !searchValue) {
      return orders;
    }

    searchValue = searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return orders.filter(order =>
      this.date.transform(order.datePayment, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss').includes(searchValue) ||
      this.currency.transform(order.tot, 'EUR', 'symbol', '.2-2', 'it').includes(searchValue) ||
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx @Felix , it works but I also had to add in app.module.ts the 'providers'  DatePipe and  CurrencyPipe ( maybe it can be helpful for someonelse )